# Server unable to execute EWS autodiscover

Tags: c#, exchangewebservices, autodiscovery

On our testing server, EWS autodiscover does not work. To eliminate an ill-set IIS option from the list of causes, I C&P'ed together a WindowsForms Application (code below) and put it, together with the `Microsoft.Exchange.Webservice.dll`, into a folder on which I have write permission.

Unfortunately, neither xml nor text file are created. Instead, I get an `Unhandled Exception` error.

```
System.NullReferenceException 
   at System.Windows.Forms.TextBoxBase.AppendText(String text)
```

This does not happen on my development machine, which is in the same AD domain and on which the test app always returns that autodiscover was successful.

Question: How come no Trace output is generated?

So now, my app code:

Form1.cs

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices;
using Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices.Data;

namespace ADDebugWin
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public static string traceData;
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            ExchangeService ews = new ExchangeService(ExchangeVersion.Exchange2010);
            ews.TraceListener = new TraceListener();
            // Optional flags to indicate the requests and responses to trace.
            ews.TraceFlags = TraceFlags.EwsRequest | TraceFlags.EwsResponse;
            ews.TraceEnabled = true;
            ews.UseDefaultCredentials = true;
            try {
                ews.AutodiscoverUrl("email@mydomain.com");
                textBox1.AppendText("AutoDiscover erfolgreich.");
            } catch (Exception ex) {
                textBox1.AppendText(traceData);
                textBox1.AppendText(ex.Message + "\r\n" + ex.StackTrace);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

TraceListener.cs

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using ADDebugMvc.Controllers;
using Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices.Data;
using System.Xml;

namespace ADDebugMvc.Models
{

    class TraceListener : ITraceListener
    {
        public void Trace(string traceType, string traceMessage)
        {
            CreateXMLTextFile(traceType, traceMessage.ToString());
            HomeController.traceData += traceType + " " + traceMessage.ToString() + "\r\n";
        }

        private void CreateXMLTextFile(string fileName, string traceContent)
        {
            // Create a new XML file for the trace information.
            try
            {
                // If the trace data is valid XML, create an XmlDocument object and save.
                XmlDocument xmlDoc = new XmlDocument();
                xmlDoc.Load(traceContent);
                xmlDoc.Save(fileName + ".xml");
            }
            catch
            {
                // If the trace data is not valid XML, save it as a text document.
                System.IO.File.WriteAllText(fileName + ".txt", traceContent);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One should note that

```
 ews.TraceFlags = TraceFlags.EwsRequest | TraceFlags.EwsResponse;
```

is not returning any Traces during AutoDiscover.

(`ews.TraceFlags = TraceFlags.All;` does.)

So no string is appended to traceData, which is why `traceData==null` -> Exception when appending it to a TextBox.